How to deploy Node-PHP-Runner Node JS Package in Heroku
I have a Node JS application and I'm currently using Node-PHP-Runner Package to run a PHP scripts within it. The application functioned as expected on my local device, but after deploying it to Heroku, I started receiving the following error from Node-PHP-Runner  below:
2024-10-13T15:22:09.791664+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: php: not found
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792495+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: PHP process exited with code 127
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792498+00:00 app[web.1]:     at runWithData (/app/node_modules/php/index.js:35:11)
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792500+00:00 app[web.1]:     at View.__express [as engine] (/app/node_modules/php/index.js:41:20)
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at View.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792504+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryRender (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:657:10)
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792504+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:609:3)
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792504+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1049:7)
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792505+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_server.js:196:7
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:149:13)
2024-10-13T15:22:09.792522+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:119:3)

What would be the solution for this?
Note: My buildpacks in Heroku include only Node.js because, when I add the PHP buildpack, Node.js doesn't seem to work.

"To use this module, you must have PHP installed and in your PATH."

thanks for the feedback @AlexHowansky but i would like to know how to do it specifically in heroku? I tried to push the PHP source code in the project's directory but still receiving the error

Hello, already resolved this, I just added PHP as an additional heroku buildpack and added a Procfile in the directory with a content of "web: node node_server.js" thank you!
